# Setting Up Pig on a multi-user hadoop cluster

Tags: permissions, hadoop, apache-pig

I have setup a multi-user Hadoop cluster where there is an admin user who has access to starting/stopping Hadoop cluster.
I'm able to run pig jobs using this admin user. However, any other user is not able to run pig scripts on the cluster.
I figured out after doing some reading that perhaps `pig.temp.dir` variable needs to be setup properly in pig-properties. But I tried creating /tmp directory in HDFS and giving it 777 permission. Then also, I'm getting permission error.
See the following error. The surprising thing is, it says: `inode="home"` in error whereas I had specified /tmp directory in pig-properties.

```
2012-04-27 08:20:57,113 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backend error: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=tavasthi, access=WRITE, inode="home":dsslmn:supergroup:rwxr-xr-x
```

Comment: I have solved the issue. The problem was with the permission settings of staging directory under mapred.